# Python Pandas - What is Pandas version of replace or append while working with multiple values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I am creating a new data frame using .str.contains. This is working okay, however I am then trying to find data and then add 'NEW' to the front however the way I am doing it is creating 'NEWX|Y|Z" when I want 'NEWX' where it finds X and 'NEWY' where it finds Y etc.

```
substr = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
df1 = df[df['short_description'].str.contains('|'.join(substr), na=False)]
```

Finds the correct rows

But when I try to append NEW to the front

```
df3['short_description'] = df3['short_description'].str.replace('|'.join(substr),'NEW'+'_'+'|'.join(substr))
```

it adds 'NEWX|Y|Z' in front of each one it finds. I understand why it is doing that but I just want NEWX to replace X, NEWY to replace Y etc.

How can I make it only replace like for like?

X / Y and Z aren't always at start of column so that's why I am finding and replacing and not just adding 'NEW' to whole dataframe column

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use capture group:

```
s = pd.Series(["Xsomething", "Ythatthing", "WhatZ", "Nothing"])
s.str.replace("(%s)" % "|".join("XYZ"), "NEW\\1", regex=True)
```

Output:

```
0    NEWXsomething
1    NEWYthatthing
2         WhatNEWZ
3          Nothing
dtype: object
```

Capture group works like *use what you found*.

1. `"(X|Y|Z)"` is looking for either of `X`, `Y` or `Z`, and keep it as a first captured group (effect of wrapping with `()`.)

   - Note that if you use multiple `()`, you can use `\\1`,`\\2`,...`\\n`.
2. Then `NEW\\1` uses this capture group to replace into `NEW{capture_group_1}`.

Comment: Thank you, that's great.

Can you explain what its doing please?

Doing below also allows me to add in _ where needed 
```
df3['short_description'] = df3['short_description'].str.replace("(%s)" % "|".join(substr), '_'+"NEW\\1", regex=True)

Comment: @Demo added some explanation. Let me know if you need more clarity ;)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I hadn't used capture groups before but makes sense.